# How to import LDIF file into LDAP server

Tags: spring-ldap

I just installed OpenLDAP and I'm trying to import an ldif file to my LDAP Server, but I got this message error :
Error while importing LDIF
 - [LDAP: error code 32 - NO_SUCH_OBJECT: failed for MessageType : ADD_REQUES
java.lang.Exception: [LDAP: error code 32 - NO_SUCH_OBJECT: failed for MessageType : ADD_REQUEST

Comment: always do code snippets in questions - what you are exactly doing, java code example here will be better of all

Answer (score 0):

The LDAP error code 32 (no such object) means that you try to import into a subtree that does not exist.

Let's assume that your tree only consist of the root entry `dc=acme,dc=com`.

If you try to create `cn=somegroup,ou=groups,dc=acme,dc=com` (either through ldapadd or through importing an LDIF file) you will get this error, because the entry `ou=groups,dc=acme,dc=com` does not exist.